# Why I have just printing red code in console error when trying to make sure that html total is same as ruby total

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-stripe-api

So I somehow built that it pass total to index page,and now I need that total to matches total in ruby script,in ruby script i have 1099 $ hardcoded but i dont want to hardcode it , instead I want that it matches total of index.html page.

so heres my code of index page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stripe Sample</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A demo of Stripe" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="./payment.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span id="total" style='display: none;'></span>
    <div class="sr-root">
      <div class="sr-main">
        <h1>Pay with a bunch of payment option</h1>

        <form id="payment-form" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    
          <div id="payment-element"></div>

          <button>Pay</button><!--Make functional-->

          <!--Make total price hidden and that total of this is same as in checkout and that its connected to ruby-->
          <div id="error-messages"></div>
        </form>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    // get the value of the "total" parameter from the URL
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const total = urlParams.get("total");

    // set the value of the hidden input field to the total value
    const totalInput = document.getElementById("total-input");
    totalInput.value = total;
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my whole ruby script

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'stripe'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dotenv'
require 'mail'
enable :sessions  

# Replace if using a different env file or config
Dotenv.load

# For sample support and debugging, not required for production:
Stripe.set_app_info(
  'stripe-samples/<name-of-sample>/[<name-of-integration-type>]',
  version: '0.0.1',
  url: 'https://github.com/stripe-samples'
)
Stripe.api_version = '2020-08-27'
Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

set :static, true
set :public_folder, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ENV['STATIC_DIR'])
set :port, 4242

# Define a global array to store the products added to cart
$cart_items = []

# Define a route to add products to the cart
post '/cart' do
  request.body.rewind
  product = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  $cart_items.push(product)
  content_type :json
  { cart_size: $cart_items.size }.to_json
end

# Define a route to get the cart items
get '/cart' do
  content_type :json
  $cart_items.to_json
end

get '/' do
  content_type 'text/html'
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end

get '/config' do
  content_type 'application/json'
  {
    publishableKey: ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  }.to_json
end

post '/create-payment-intent' do
  total = data['total']
  payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
    amount: total,
    currency: 'eur',
    automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true }
  })
  { clientSecret: payment_intent.client_secret }.to_json
end

get '/complete' do
  # Retrieve the payment intent object from Stripe
  payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(params[:payment_intent])

  # Check if the payment was successful
  if payment_intent.status == "succeeded"
    # Redirect to success page (optional)
    redirect '/success.html'
  else
    # Redirect to error page
    redirect '/error'
  end
end

post '/webhook' do
  # You can use webhooks to receive information about asynchronous payment events.
  # For more about our webhook events check out https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks.
  webhook_secret = ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET']
  payload = request.body.read
  if !webhook_secret.empty?
    # Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret if webhook signing is configured.
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = nil

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, webhook_secret
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      # Invalid payload
      status 400
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts '⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.'
      status 400
      return
    end
  else
    data = JSON.parse(payload, symbolize_names: true)
    event = Stripe::Event.construct_from(data)
  end

  case event.type
  when 'payment_intent.succeeded'
    puts '  Payment received!'
  end

  content_type 'application/json'
  {
    status: 'success'
  }.to_json
end
```

The problem is that when I type Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -UseBasicParsing in console to run /create-payment-intent,it print a bunch of red code:

```html
              server.rb in
                block in &lt;main&gt;





                  content_type &#x27;application&#x2F;json&#x27;

                  {

                    publishableKey: ENV[&#x27;STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY&#x27;],

                  }.to_json

                end



                post &#x27;&#x2F;create-payment-intent&#x27; do




                  total = data[&#x27;total&#x27;]




                  payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({

                    amount: total,

                    currency: &#x27;eur&#x27;,

                    automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true }

                  })

                  { clientSecret: payment_intent.client_secret }.to_json

                end






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                call







                        pattern                 = compile(path, route_mustermann_opts)

                        method_name             = &quot;#{verb} #{path}&quot;

                        unbound_method          = generate_method(method_name, &amp;block)

                        conditions = @conditions

                        @conditions = []

                        wrapper = block.arity.zero? ?




                          proc { |a, _p| unbound_method.bind(a).call } :




                          proc { |a, p| unbound_method.bind(a).call(*p) }



                        [pattern, conditions, wrapper]

                      end



                      def compile(path, route_mustermann_opts = {})

                        Mustermann.new(path, **mustermann_opts.merge(route_mustermann_opts))






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block in compile!







                        pattern                 = compile(path, route_mustermann_opts)

                        method_name             = &quot;#{verb} #{path}&quot;

                        unbound_method          = generate_method(method_name, &amp;block)

                        conditions = @conditions

                        @conditions = []

                        wrapper = block.arity.zero? ?




                          proc { |a, _p| unbound_method.bind(a).call } :




                          proc { |a, p| unbound_method.bind(a).call(*p) }



                        [pattern, conditions, wrapper]

                      end



                      def compile(path, route_mustermann_opts = {})

                        Mustermann.new(path, **mustermann_opts.merge(route_mustermann_opts))






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block (3 levels) in route!





                      routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]



                      routes&amp;.each do |pattern, conditions, block|

                        response.delete_header(&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;) unless @pinned_response



                        returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, conditions) do |*args|

                          env[&#x27;sinatra.route&#x27;] = &quot;#{@request.request_method} #{pattern}&quot;




                          route_eval { block[*args] }




                        end



                        # don&#x27;t wipe out pass_block in superclass

                        pass_block = returned_pass_block if returned_pass_block

                      end



                      # Run routes defined in superclass.






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                route_eval







                      route_eval(&amp;pass_block) if pass_block

                      route_missing

                    end



                    # Run a route block and throw :halt with the result.

                    def route_eval




                      throw :halt, yield




                    end



                    # If the current request matches pattern and conditions, fill params

                    # with keys and call the given block.

                    # Revert params afterwards.

                    #

                    # Returns pass block.






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block (2 levels) in route!





                      routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]



                      routes&amp;.each do |pattern, conditions, block|

                        response.delete_header(&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;) unless @pinned_response



                        returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, conditions) do |*args|

                          env[&#x27;sinatra.route&#x27;] = &quot;#{@request.request_method} #{pattern}&quot;




                          route_eval { block[*args] }




                        end



                        # don&#x27;t wipe out pass_block in superclass

                        pass_block = returned_pass_block if returned_pass_block

                      end



                      # Run routes defined in superclass.






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block in process_route





                        @params[:captures] = force_encoding(captures) unless captures.nil? || captures.empty?

                      else

                        values += params.values.flatten

                      end



                      catch(:pass) do

                        conditions.each { |c| throw :pass if c.bind(self).call == false }




                        block ? block[self, values] : yield(self, values)




                      end

                    rescue StandardError

                      @env[&#x27;sinatra.error.params&#x27;] = @params

                      raise

                    ensure

                      params ||= {}

                      params.each { |k, _| @params.delete(k) } unless @env[&#x27;sinatra.error.params&#x27;]






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                catch





                        captures           = pattern.match(route).captures.map { |c| URI_INSTANCE.unescape(c) if c }    

                        values            += captures

                        @params[:captures] = force_encoding(captures) unless captures.nil? || captures.empty?

                      else

                        values += params.values.flatten

                      end






                      catch(:pass) do




                        conditions.each { |c| throw :pass if c.bind(self).call == false }

                        block ? block[self, values] : yield(self, values)

                      end

                    rescue StandardError

                      @env[&#x27;sinatra.error.params&#x27;] = @params

                      raise

                    ensure






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                process_route





                        captures           = pattern.match(route).captures.map { |c| URI_INSTANCE.unescape(c) if c }

                        values            += captures

                        @params[:captures] = force_encoding(captures) unless captures.nil? || captures.empty?

                      else

                        values += params.values.flatten

                      end






                      catch(:pass) do




                        conditions.each { |c| throw :pass if c.bind(self).call == false }

                        block ? block[self, values] : yield(self, values)

                      end

                    rescue StandardError

                      @env[&#x27;sinatra.error.params&#x27;] = @params

                      raise

                    ensure






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block in route!





                    # Run routes defined on the class and all superclasses.

                    def route!(base = settings, pass_block = nil)

                      routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]



                      routes&amp;.each do |pattern, conditions, block|

                        response.delete_header(&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;) unless @pinned_response






                        returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, conditions) do |*args|




                          env[&#x27;sinatra.route&#x27;] = &quot;#{@request.request_method} #{pattern}&quot;

                          route_eval { block[*args] }

                        end



                        # don&#x27;t wipe out pass_block in superclass

                        pass_block = returned_pass_block if returned_pass_block

                      end






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                each





                      end

                    end



                    # Run routes defined on the class and all superclasses.

                    def route!(base = settings, pass_block = nil)

                      routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]






                      routes&amp;.each do |pattern, conditions, block|




                        response.delete_header(&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;) unless @pinned_response



                        returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, conditions) do |*args|

                          env[&#x27;sinatra.route&#x27;] = &quot;#{@request.request_method} #{pattern}&quot;

                          route_eval { block[*args] }

                        end








        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                route!





                      end

                    end



                    # Run routes defined on the class and all superclasses.

                    def route!(base = settings, pass_block = nil)

                      routes = base.routes[@request.request_method]






                      routes&amp;.each do |pattern, conditions, block|




                        response.delete_header(&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;) unless @pinned_response



                        returned_pass_block = process_route(pattern, conditions) do |*args|

                          env[&#x27;sinatra.route&#x27;] = &quot;#{@request.request_method} #{pattern}&quot;

                          route_eval { block[*args] }

                        end








        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block in dispatch!





                      end



                      invoke do

                        static! if settings.static? &amp;&amp; (request.get? || request.head?)

                        filter! :before do

                          @pinned_response = !response[&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;].nil?

                        end




                        route!




                      end

                    rescue ::Exception =&gt; e

                      invoke { handle_exception!(e) }

                    ensure

                      begin

                        filter! :after unless env[&#x27;sinatra.static_file&#x27;]

                      rescue ::Exception =&gt; e






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                catch





                      env[&#x27;sinatra.static_file&#x27;] = path

                      cache_control(*settings.static_cache_control) if settings.static_cache_control?

                      send_file path, options.merge(disposition: nil)

                    end



                    # Run the block with &#x27;throw :halt&#x27; support and apply result to the response.

                    def invoke(&amp;block)




                      res = catch(:halt, &amp;block)






                      res = [res] if (Integer === res) || (String === res)

                      if (Array === res) &amp;&amp; (Integer === res.first)

                        res = res.dup

                        status(res.shift)

                        body(res.pop)

                        headers(*res)






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                invoke





                      env[&#x27;sinatra.static_file&#x27;] = path

                      cache_control(*settings.static_cache_control) if settings.static_cache_control?

                      send_file path, options.merge(disposition: nil)

                    end



                    # Run the block with &#x27;throw :halt&#x27; support and apply result to the response.

                    def invoke(&amp;block)




                      res = catch(:halt, &amp;block)






                      res = [res] if (Integer === res) || (String === res)

                      if (Array === res) &amp;&amp; (Integer === res.first)

                        res = res.dup

                        status(res.shift)

                        body(res.pop)

                        headers(*res)






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                dispatch!





                      @params.merge!(@request.params).each do |key, val|

                        next unless val.respond_to?(:force_encoding)



                        val = val.dup if val.frozen?

                        @params[key] = force_encoding(val)

                      end






                      invoke do




                        static! if settings.static? &amp;&amp; (request.get? || request.head?)

                        filter! :before do

                          @pinned_response = !response[&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;].nil?

                        end

                        route!

                      end

                    rescue ::Exception =&gt; e






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                block in call!





                      @env      = env

                      @params   = IndifferentHash.new

                      @request  = Request.new(env)

                      @response = Response.new

                      @pinned_response = nil

                      template_cache.clear if settings.reload_templates






                      invoke { dispatch! }




                      invoke { error_block!(response.status) } unless @env[&#x27;sinatra.error&#x27;]



                      unless @response[&#x27;Content-Type&#x27;]

                        if Array === body &amp;&amp; body[0].respond_to?(:content_type)

                          content_type body[0].content_type

                        elsif (default = settings.default_content_type)

                          content_type default






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                catch





                      env[&#x27;sinatra.static_file&#x27;] = path

                      cache_control(*settings.static_cache_control) if settings.static_cache_control?

                      send_file path, options.merge(disposition: nil)

                    end



                    # Run the block with &#x27;throw :halt&#x27; support and apply result to the response.

                    def invoke(&amp;block)




                      res = catch(:halt, &amp;block)






                      res = [res] if (Integer === res) || (String === res)

                      if (Array === res) &amp;&amp; (Integer === res.first)

                        res = res.dup

                        status(res.shift)

                        body(res.pop)

                        headers(*res)






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web&#x2F;Ruby31-x64&#x2F;lib&#x2F;ruby&#x2F;gems&#x2F;3.1.0&#x2F;gems&#x2F;sinatra-3.0.5&#x2F;lib 
&#x2F;sinatra&#x2F;base.rb in
                invoke





                      env[&#x27;sinatra.static_file&#x27;] = path

                      cache_control(*settings.static_cache_control) if settings.static_cache_control?

                      send_file path, options.merge(disposition: nil)

                    end



                    # Run the block with &#x27;throw :halt&#x27; support and apply result to the response.

                    def invoke(&amp;block)




                      res = catch(:halt, &amp;block)






                      res = [res] if (Integer === res) || (String === res)

                      if (Array === res) &amp;&amp; (Integer === res.first)

                        res = res.dup

                        status(res.shift)

                        body(res.pop)

                        headers(*res)






        
      


              C:&#x2F;web
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri http://localhost:4242/create-paym ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc  
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand       
PS C:\s\starter-ruby>
```

Comment: _"it print a bunch of red code that I can't explain"_ – maybe we can, show the error messages, please.

Comment: When I had 1099 hardcoded for amount it did correctly run that command and when I changed 1099 into total It now does not work

Comment: No need to paste it in comments – use the [edit] function to update your question.

Comment: You didnt answer for a while so i tried something different : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76166965/invoke-webrequest-method-post-uri-http-localhost4242-create-payment-intent